# preg_replace to remove stand-alone numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm looking to replace all standalone numbers from a string where the number has no adjacent characters (including dashes), example:

> Test 3 string 49Test 49test9 9

Should return Test string 49Test 49Test9

So far I've been playing around with:

```
   $str = 'Test 3 string 49Test 49test9 9';
   $str= preg_replace('/[^a-z\-]+(\d+)[^a-z\-]+?/isU', ' ', $str);
   echo $str;
```

However with no luck, this returns

> Test string 9Test 9test9

leaving out part of the string, i thought to add [0-9] to the matches, but to no avail, what am I missing, seems so simple?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you wanting to replace the numbers with a single space character (as in your example) or simply remove them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using a word boundary and negative look-arounds for hyphens, eg

```
$str = preg_replace('/\b(?<!-)\d+(?!-)\b/', '', $str);
```

Comment: This works except I need to allow 2-test as well, sorry if I wasn't too clear on that :-)

Comment: @user1041334 I've added a possible solution to the hyphen issue using negative look-arounds. See if that works

Comment: +1 it works. And a bit more readable than mine, having the word boundaries outside the look arounds.

Comment: Yes works perfectly, can't believe I haven't used stackoverflow before!

Answer (score 1):

Not that complicated, if you watch the spaces :)

```
<?php
$str = 'Test 3 string 49Test 49test9 9';
$str = preg_replace('/(\s(\d+)\s|\s(\d+)$|^(\d+)\s)/iU', '', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: Actually; I stand corrected. @Phil's answer is probably a better solution than mine. I just didn't know about \b yet. I do now. StackOverflow is cool.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I tried to cover your additional requirement to not match on 5-abc

```
\s*(?<!\B|-)\d+(?!\B|-)\s*
```

and **replace with a single space**!

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v5uu)

The problem then is to extend the word boundary with the character `-`. I achieved this by using negative look arounds and looking for `-` or `\B` (not a word boundary)

Additionally I am matching the surrounding whitespace with the `\s*`, therefore you have to replace with a single space.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using
`explode(" ",$str)`
to get an array of the "words" in your string. Then it should be easier to filter out single numbers.